# findChild() in qt jambi is not working for me

Tags: java, qt, qt-jambi

i'm looking for a code snippet that uses the findChild() function in qt jambi
i've looked on google but it seems that qt jambi is not well documented
any way here is what i found in the documentation :

```
public final QObject findChild(java.lang.Class cl,
                           java.lang.String name)

This functions searches for descendant(s) of this QObject.
```

let take a QLabel for exemple ,if we want to look for a QLabel named "myLabel" ,the syntaxe should be like this :

```
QLabel l = this.findChild(QLabel,"MyLabel");
```

i tried this code and its not working.
ps: in qt the syntaxe for this is :

```
findChildren<QLabel *>("myLabel");
```

any suggestions ? how to convert it to java syntax ?

Answer (score 1):

To get the Class object for a class QLabel, you write "QLabel.class" -- i.e.,

```
QLabel l = this.findChild(QLabel.class,"MyLabel");
```

I don't know if it's genericized or not, or if you have to cast the result:

```
QLabel l = (QLabel) this.findChild(QLabel.class,"MyLabel");
```